# Can't install MySQL 8 any more in Debian 8

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

Debian 8 just won't install MySQL 8.0. I try with a clean VMware virtual machine, nothing installed before.

As I try to use the newest mysql-apt-config repo (0.8.12-1_all.deb), mysql 8 is pre-selected in the dialog [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ARH.png)

[image]

but even as soon as I try to select the server version, I don't see version 8 any more [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9jC0.png)

[image]

Anyway, if I continue leaving it pre-selected with version 8, it also won't fetch version 8 with apt-get, but 5.5 .. [picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKXBm.png)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Indeed, the automatic installation gives always MySQL 5.5

I ended up using manual installation as follows : [manual installation using debian package](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-debian.html)